# PySpark sort values

Tags: apache-spark, sorting, pyspark, mapreduce, rdd

I have a data:

```
[(u'ab', u'cd'),
 (u'ef', u'gh'),
 (u'cd', u'ab'),
 (u'ab', u'gh'),
 (u'ab', u'cd')]
```

I would like to do a mapreduce on this data and to find out how often same pairs appear.

As a result I get:

```
[((u'ab', u'cd'), 2),
 ((u'cd', u'ab'), 1),
 ((u'ab', u'gh'), 1),
 ((u'ef', u'gh'), 1)]
```

As you can see it is not quire right as (u'ab', u'cd') has to be 3 instead of 2 because (u'cd', u'ab') is the same pair.

My question is how can I make the program to count (u'cd', u'ab') and (u'ab', u'cd') as the same pair? I was thinking about sorting values for each row but could not find any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the values then use `reduceByKey` to count the pairs:

```
rdd1 = rdd.map(lambda x: (tuple(sorted(x)), 1))\
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)

rdd1.collect()
# [(('ab', 'gh'), 1), (('ef', 'gh'), 1), (('ab', 'cd'), 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can key by the sorted element, and count by key:

```
result = rdd.keyBy(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).countByKey()

print(result)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {('ab', 'cd'): 3, ('ef', 'gh'): 1, ('ab', 'gh'): 1})
```

To convert the result into a list, you can do:

```
result2 = sorted(result.items())

print(result2)
# [(('ab', 'cd'), 3), (('ab', 'gh'), 1), (('ef', 'gh'), 1)]
```